# Only first button to open bootstrap model works in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a forum, and a have made to open bootstrap modal when someone clicks on Reply Button, but that button is in while loop and modal opens only on first button in row.

This is while loop

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_answers WHERE topicId = :id");
                $sql->bindValue(":id", $id);
                $sql->execute();
                while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    if($row['quote'] == "")
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <b><?php echo $row['uid']; ?></b>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                                        <?php echo $row['date']; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['answer']; ?></p>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddReply"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-reply"></i> Reply</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <b><?php echo $row['uid']; ?></b>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                                        <?php echo $row['date']; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <blockquote class="blockquote" style="background-color: #F8F8F8;"><?php echo $row['quote']; ?></blockquote>
                                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['answer']; ?></p>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddReply"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-reply"></i> Reply</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
```

This is a modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addReply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add Reply</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Quote</label>
                        <?php
                            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT answer FROM forum_answers WHERE id=:id");
                            $sql->bindValue(":id", $id);
                            $sql->execute();
                            while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                ?>
                                <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" name="quote" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="4" disabled><?php echo $row['answer']; ?></textarea>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Answer</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="desc1" cols="40" rows="3" name="answer" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit3" value="Reply">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnAddReply").click(function() {
            $("#addReply").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't know how to use class instead id in bootstrap, I am not so great with javascript.

Comment: attribute `ID` must be unique for html > ver. 4, which means you cannot have 2 or more elements with the same ID within the same web page.

Comment: You should use class selectors instead of ids.

Comment: How to use name of modal class when in bootstrap all are same `class="modal fade"` , when I change it in JS, it opens all modals from that page. Is there a way to set unique class selector in bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have more than one id with the same name it by default select the first one with the name when js on click event trigger in your case.

you can use jQuery like operator to trigger on click event for all the ids with name `btnAddReply`

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("[id^=btnAddReply]").click(function() {
                $("#addReply").modal();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

but a clean and better solution is to use a common class. instead of id in your HTML give the class with name `btnAddReply`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".btnAddReply").click(function() {
            $("#addReply").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```